# Simple Lambda Calculus Question

Tags: lambda-calculus, normal-forms

For any 2 strongly normalizing terms in the Simply Typed Lambda Calculus, s and t, is st also strongly normalizing? And why? I'm a bit confused as this is used in a proof regarding strong normalization and the typable lambda calculus, but I have not been able to show that this is the case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/52349/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156607/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.